# Android TV Set screensaver intent

Tags: android, android-tv, screensaver

There's no possibility to open preview of screensaver like for a live wallpaper so I'd like to provide a shortcut for users to open TV's settings and manually set screensaver.

Currently I open system settings with intent action `android.settings.SETTINGS` which opens root device settings.

On phones I can start `android.settings.DREAM_SETTINGS` (it is described in docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_DREAM_SETTINGS)) which opens corresponding settings section. But this doesn't work on TV (tried on emulator). Is it possible to open it on Android TV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way to launch this activity in the source code of "Aerial Dream" screensaver: https://github.com/cachapa/AerialDream/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/codingbuffalo/aerialdream/SettingsFragment.java#L29

```java
// Check if the daydream intent is available - some devices (e.g. NVidia Shield) do not support it
Intent intent = new Intent(SCREENSAVER_SETTINGS);
if (!intentAvailable(intent)) {
    // Try opening the daydream settings activity directly: https://gist.github.com/reines/bc798a2cb539f51877bb279125092104
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setClassName("com.android.tv.settings", "com.android.tv.settings.device.display.daydream.DaydreamActivity");
    if (!intentAvailable(intent)) {
        // If all else fails, open the normal settings screen
        intent = new Intent(SETTINGS);
    }
}
startActivity(intent);

private boolean intentAvailable(Intent intent) {
    PackageManager manager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    return !infos.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Use this for adb: `am start -n com.android.tv.settings/.device.display.daydream.DaydreamActivity`

Answer (score 4):

Just in case somebody looks for launching screensaver on Nvidia Shield.

The intent name is `com.android.systemui/.Somnambulator`.

If using Button Mapper app, use "Broadcase Intent" with "Package": `com.android.systemui` and "Component": `com.android.systemui.Somnambulator`.